# how to change jquery ui autocomplete function suitable for python

Tags: jquery, python

Instead of using search.php within this example, how can i use a python method to return the data? example: is this valid: $.getJSON( "{{ data }}", {
                        term: extractLast( request.term )
                    }, response );

```
       $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#birds" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "search.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: You should probably add the code to search.php, and perhaps whatever python code you already have.

Comment: i think thats not relevant because i am not using any php setup. So i definitely need to use something else

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question. It seems that you're asking how to switch from php to python on the server side. If that is not the case, then I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I don't understand where python fits into this picture. Is this javascript code generated using python?

Comment: So `{{ data }}` is some kind of template placeholder that will be replaced with the actual python data? What python framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have your python script print a JSON formatted string for a data array. I would be willing to bet the python has a library you may load for converting objects, array, strings, etc into JSON formatted strings. Simple turn the appropriate array into a JSON string and your JavaScript will load it, now what exactly your suppose to return, I can't tell from this example.

Good luck!

Comment: Somehing like ?$.getJSON( "{{ tag_list }}", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );

Comment: so in the JavaScript you should point to a python file instead of a php file. Something like `search.py`. In that python file you need to literarly print a JSON formatted string. Read more about JSON at http://www.json.org/. Whatever you print "to the screen" will be returned to JavaScript via AJAX (including errors and warnings!).

Comment: Sorry if I was bit confusing on that last one, AJAX works by calling an external file and that is what your python script will be, external to all the JavaScript code. So make a new file named `search.py` alongside the page with the javascript code and place your python code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I use simplejson package. You didn't say what Python framework you want to use. Something like this is typical:

json = simplejson.dumps(obj)
return HttpResponse(json, "application/json")

For a more complete implementation you can look at my [json.py module](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/json.py).